# Python Notebook in RStudio

Tags: python, r, rstudio

Hey is it possible to create Python notebook in RStudio in the same way as I can create R notebook? I would like to have one program for both R and Python language.

Comment: Unless I’m missing something big, the answer is *no*.

Comment: You may use an R Markdown notebook with a Python engine in RStudio Open Source Edition. Jupyter notebooks are only available from RStudio Server Pro though.